# Как увеличить быстродействие сравнения элементов класса?

Tags: c#, list

Есть список `artList` в котором ~60т данных.
Есть также список объектов класса `List<FileDB> listFileDB = new List<FileDB>();` В нем тоже порядка ~60т данных.

```
class FileDB
    {
        public string Articule { get; set; }
        public string Naim { get; set; }
        public string Cnt { get; set; }

    }
```

Вопрос. Очень много процессорного времени занимает операция сравнения. Вроде и регулярок тут нет, и split не юзаю. Как ускорить процесс сравнения?

```
 for (int i = 0; i < artList.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j <listFileDB.Count; j++)
                    {
                        if (artList[i] == listFileDB[j].Articule)
                        {
                             // Данная операция очень затратна по ресурсам
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: А что именно вы хотите сделать? У вас двойной цикл, наверняка можно сэкономить время, если воспользоваться более подходящей структурой данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если быть точным, то много времени занимает не сама операция сравнения, а перебор большого числа элементов внтри цикла (вложенные циклы).
Если ваша задача состоит в том, чтобы найти совпадающие элементы в двух коллекциях и совершить над ними некоторое действие, более быстрым может оказаться следующий подход:

```
HashSet<string> set1 = new HashSet<string>(artList);
HashSet<string> set2 = new HashSet<string>(listFileDb.Select(a => a.Articule));
var res = set1.Intersect(set2);
foreach (var item in res)
{
// Do whatever you want
}
```

В списке (List) время сложность доступа к элементу является линейной (растет пропорционально размеру списка). С учетов обработки двух списков во вложенных циклах, сложность оказывается квадратичной. В хеш-наборе (HashSet) - время доступа к элементу константно. За счет этого получается существенный выигрыш по скорости. Порядком элементов в данном случае придется пожертвовать, однако во многих ситуациях это некритично.

---

Update 1
Если для дальнейшей работы требуются исходные элементы из listFileDb, попробуйте следующее:

```
var selectedItems = listFileDb.Where(item => set1.Contains(item.Articule));
```

set2 в этом случае объявлять не нужно. Должно получиться существенно быстрее, чем изначальный пример, со вложенными циклами.

Comment: судя по вопросу в _artList_ строки, поэтому Select не нужен

Comment: Согласен, исправил.

Comment: и еще открытый вопрос: что именно автор хочет видеть в `res`, если объекты из _listFileDb_, то приведенный пример не подходит

Comment: я просто потом из listFileDB использую еще два поля, поэтому не могу сделать выборку по одному полю

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Вообще говоря, вам стоило бы использовать альтернативные структуры данных. Например, словарь ([`Dictionary<string,FileDB>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx)). Или вместо artList можно использовать [`HashSet<string>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx)

Но можно обойтись и списками - если делать Join:

```
var pairs = from x in artList
            join y in listFileDB on x equals y.Articule
            select y;
```

Внутри там, к слову, будет все тот же словарь, только временный.